# Is it possible to create JSON key file from Google Cloud user

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

I have `test@gmail.com` which is have role to access stakeholder bucket.

By the way, my application that working on Airflow Connection need to authenticate from JSON file key that was generated from ServiceAccount.

But in this case I do not allow to create Service Account to being abstract user.

anyone have solution for this?

Comment: Is it a gmail account or do you have a corporate (org) account?

Comment: I think would be org account

Answer (score 0):

If it's an org account, you can create a service account with domain wide delegation. That means, the service account will be able to perform any operation on behalf any user in the organisation, CEO included.

Because it's not so safe, I prefer recommend to store the password in Secret Manager and perform a "standard login/password" authentication on the email address.

There is also tradeoff, like the impossibility to activate the MFA on that account, but I prefer that than the first solution!